# ZipCode from location

Tags: android, location, zipcode

Is there any way to get zip-code of the current user location from location or lat or long.
If so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can...All you need to do is extract the

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?ll=**latitude,longitude**

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?ll=10.345561,123.896932
```

Or try experimenting this solutions.I can give you an idea.

You can have a city right? WIth this json data, If you have a database(at maxmind.com) of the zipcode with this format

**CountryCode | City | ZipCode**

---

PH       |Cebu  |6000

Now query your database that is relative to the countrycode that googles return.

***UPDATE***

**The Geocoding API v2 has been turned down on September 9th, 2013.**

Here's the new URL of API service

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=your_latitude,your_longitude

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=10.32,123.90&sensor=true

Comment: @Udaykiran you need another database that has a record of a zipcode.This is the example of the database.http://ipinfodb.com/zipcode_database.php

Comment: If you want to download also another zipcode database,Here <a href="http://www.populardata.com/downloads.html" >ZipCode Database</a>

Comment: Thanks u just saved my day!!!!
and @Udaykiran try to give lat long of USA, it will give you the postal code, i don't know what is the problem for India!!!!

Comment: This answer is no longer valid since the Geocoding API v2 has been turned down by Google. Android Geocode API is a better solution.

Comment: how can ZIP code using lat, "long..http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=your_latitude,your_longitude" also not respond zip code...any suggestion?

Comment: FYI Zip code data is not static...it's a bad recommendation to use a static database.

Answer (score 8):

Use Android [Geocoder API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)!

getFromLocation(double, double, int) is all you need.

Answer (score 5):

Geocoder based implementation:

```
private String getZipCodeFromLocation(Location location) {
    Address addr = getAddressFromLocation(location);
    return addr.getPostalCode() == null ? "" : addr.getPostalCode();
}

private Address getAddressFromLocation(Location location) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    Address address = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addr = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addr.size() > 0) {
            address = addr.get(0);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return address;
}
```

You can get also other information from address, for example city name.