# How to get zip code or area code of the current location in android?

Tags: android, zipcode

I would like to get the zip code of the current location in android device for my app,any example or snippet on locating it. I have tried geocoder it gives lat & long position only.

Comment: did you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855843/zipcode-from-location

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are clearly not using it right then...

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
// lat,lng, your current location
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

Now the list of `Address` contains the closest known areas. The `Address` object has the `getPostalCode()` function. Grab the first object and find it's Postal code.

There you go.

Comment: Hi @st0le, I am getting `5-1-304, Koti Main Rd, Badi Chowdi, Koti` as a result when I am calling `addresses.get(0)).getAddressLine(0))` . But I am getting null when I am calling `addresses.get(0)).getPostalCode())` . Please help me to get only pincode.

Comment: @SudheerKumar, It's probably not filled in. Try the other AddressLine(1..n). You can correct the data by making a request at Google

Comment: What are `lat` and `lng` in this situation? Obviously latitude and longitude, but if I am trying to get the users location, how do I know what their latitude and longitude are?

Comment: @AdamMc331, that's part of another question.

Answer (score 2):

Check our the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class in Android. That class has getFromLocation method which works for me. You could use like the following in your activity.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

[Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) class docs

If it doesn't for some reason you should look for a reverse geocoding service

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) carefully.

The **getFromLocation** method is what you need.