# How to get postal code using user current location in android

Tags: android, zipcode

I am trying to get postal code, but I am unable to get zipcode(postalcode). I can able to get current city  but when I try to get the zipcode it's giving me a null pointer exception.
Can anyone help me.

```
final Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0)                                   Log.d(addresses.get(0).getLocality()); // I can get city name here.
Log.d(addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();// here i am getting nullpoiter exception
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get zip code or area code of the current location in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442050/how-to-get-zip-code-or-area-code-of-the-current-location-in-android)

Comment: Read the second comment on the accepted answer in the link.

Comment: Other AddressLine means?

Comment: This means - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double, double, int). Then `addresses.get(1)).getPostalCode()` or try with 2,3,4.  After you read this - take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515682/get-the-particular-address-using-latitude-and-longitude/16515848#16515848

Comment: When I used like this i got the following exception  09-02 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 1

Comment: Yes, it's becasue you're calling `List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);`. Change the last digit to 3,4 or 5.

Comment: What is the maximum value for that last digit.What it means? can you give some clarification?

Comment: The information is in the second link, but it failed to paste I think - try all, which was marked with "`````" -> `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double, double, int)`

Comment: But I can get the city name.Y should i didn't get postal code? What is the reason?

Comment: Strange ... You can do it with another approach, by using this -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ . However, paste the manifest here please.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" >
    </uses-feature>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Used google webservice to get the zipcode.

The following is the google web service

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=lattitude,longitude&sensor=true

here lattitude and longitude. so replace those values and you will get response and parse them and get postal code.

Answer (score 8):

Try to use android built-in [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to get details from latitude and longitude without calling google location api as below :

Initialize `Gecoder` using `Context` :

```
final Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context);
```

Get `Address` as result from Lat-Long, Here (10) max result.

```
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 10);
```

Iterate to result get required location details :

```
for (Address address : addresses) {
    if(address.getLocality()!=null && address.getPostalCode()!=null){
        Log.d(address.getLocality());
        Log.d(address.getPostalCode();
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I should get postalcode? I know the above solution but I need to get postal code..

Answer (score 7):

```
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    Address address=null;
    String addr="";
    String zipcode="";
    String city="";
    String state="";
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0){

            addr=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+"," +addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
                 city=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                 state=addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();

                 for(int i=0 ;i<addresses.size();i++){
                     address = addresses.get(i);
                     if(address.getPostalCode()!=null){
                         zipcode=address.getPostalCode();
                         break;
                     }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have utility method to grab postcode which is pretty neat and works fine..

```
public static String getPostalCodeByCoordinates(Context context, double lat, double lon) throws IOException {

    Geocoder mGeocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    String zipcode=null;
    Address address=null;

    if (mGeocoder != null) {

        List<Address> addresses = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 5);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {
                address = addresses.get(i);
                if (address.getPostalCode() != null) {
                    zipcode = address.getPostalCode();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Postal code: " + address.getPostalCode());
                    break;
                }

            }
            return zipcode;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```