# I want to retrieve Postal_Code/ ZipCode specifically in Pakistan using google Api or any other one

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2, google-geocoder, postal-code

I have gone through the different question here on Stackoverflow but none of them helped me out yet. I am using google API in my app and needs to retrieve the zipcode. Currently I am getting all the other parameters but zipcode.

Any suggestion/guidance or help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zHi0.png)

Geocoder geocoder;

```
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(activity, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(params[0]), Double.parseDouble(params[1]), 1);

        //get current Street name
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

        //get current province/City
        String province = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();

        //get country
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

        //get postal code
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        //get place Name
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL

        return "Street: " + address + "\n" + "City/Province: " + province + "\nCountry: " + country
                + "\nPostal CODE: " + postalCode + "\n" + "Place Name: " + knownName;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "IOE EXCEPTION";

    }
```

Comment: It seems that you'll be needing to use web service for this one as indicated in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568446/how-to-get-postal-code-using-user-current-location-in-android).

Comment: I also have used web service, that also don't show postal_code in Pakistan ....but working fine other than Pakistan....

Comment: Have you tried SmartyStreets? Demo international addresses here: https://smartystreets.com/products/single-address?country=&address1=&address2=&locality=&administrative_area=&postal_code=&address-type=international-street-components.